# Removing title tags from each page

Tags: theme-development, title

hello to all I am newbie to wordpress. I want to remove the title tags from every page.Is there any way to remove that part?Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open your theme files and remove the code that adds this to the page. The typical files to look in are:
index.php, page.php, post.php, single.php.

Look for this:

```
<h2><a href=”<?php the_permalink(); ?>”><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

or it might look like this:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

You might want to comment the part of code out so you can easily add it if you want to in the future. To use this method you would surround the part the_title(); with this /**  the_title();  */ It would then look like this:

```
<?php /**  the_title();  */?>
```